# After Catalina Update Bluetooth Headphones Turn Off Randomly

Tags: audio, bluetooth, catalina, headphones

I use my Bose bluetooth headphone daily.  Never had a problem on my macbook pro or iMac.

I updated to Catalina 10.15.1.  Now randomly the computer switches from headphones to internal speakers.  It isn't clear if the headphones are disconnected, they still show connected under the bluetooth list.  In the sound preferences I can select the headphones, but it doesn't affect the sound, and if I close and open the sound preferences the internal speakers are selected. I have to disconnect and reconnect the headphones to get it to switch back to the headphones.

[image]

I have restarted a bunch of times.

I have disconnected and reconnected.

I have removed and added the headphones as a bluetooth device.

I have deleted the bluetooth plist files in the library (/Library/Preferences + ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost ). and restarted.

I ran Apple Diagnostics, it showed nothing.

I reset NVRAM (per Udhy), still have the problem.

Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did see how does it behave if you boot from Safe Mode?

Comment: Having the same issue on 10.15.3, if I'm not actively using the audio something shuts it off even though macOS still shows it as connected. If I turn the headphones off/on it will come back.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

I did everything that I found within the different communities and blogs, finally, I find out that there is something between Whatsapp and Bluetooth. I uninstall WhatsApp and never use WhatsApp web again and problem solved.

I hope it can help in your case too until Apple figures out how to fix it.

Comment: I've tried the solutions above on my MBP Catalina OS, the only one that really works is removing WhatsApp Web, mine even affects my Bluetooth mouse. Today alone, it has both disconnected and reconnected by itself twice. My headphones disconnect or drop-offs even more often, I count 6 for the last 5 work hours. Hopefully, there's an update on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already deleted .plist file , you can try the following option.

**Reset NVRAM**

1. Shut down your Mac device.
2. Press the Power Button.
3. Before the grey screen appears, press the <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd> keys all at the same time.
4. Continues pressing the keys Mac restarts and a startup sound can be heard for the second time.
5. Finally, release the Four (4) keys:  Command, Option, P and R keys.

Your Bluetooth should work as expected after that.